# bash + match regexes for both different hostnames

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, regular-expression

In my bash script I identify the machine name - `kafka01` or `kafka02` or `kafka03`  with the following regular expression bash code

```
if [[ $(hostname -s) =~ ^kafka[[:digit:]] ]]
then
/tmp/run.sh
fi
```

Example from `hostname` command:

```
hostname -s
kafka01
```

But now we want to run the script - `/tmp/run.sh` also if the machine name is `mngkafka01` or `mngkafka02` or `mngkafka03`.

So we did the following; this should run the script `run.sh` if machine name is `kafka01` or `mngkafka01`, etc:

```
if [[ $(hostname -s) =~ ^[mng]kafka[[:digit:]] ]]
then
/tmp/run.sh
fi
```

But this regular syntax does not work.

What is wrong with my regular expression code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[mng]` does not match `mng`, it matches either `m` or `n` or `g`.
An appropriate regex is `(^|^mng)kafka[[:digit:]]+$`. This matches

- `(^|^mng)` either the null string or `mng` at the string start,
- `kafka`,
- `[[:digit:]]+$` one or more digits anchored to the string end.

Notice that your previous regex would also raise a false positive for `kafka7u`
as it was not anchored.

Test:

```bsh
arr=(kafka01 kafka7u mngkafka01 gkafka7x)
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    if [[ $i =~ (^|^mng)kafka[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
kafka01
mngkafka01
```

More information: [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html) (see `[[...]]` section).

The fixed version to your original attempt:

```bsh
if [[ $(hostname -s) =~ (^|^mng)kafka[[:digit:]]+$ ]]
then
    /tmp/run.sh
fi
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: Is there an advantage to stating `(^|^mng)` instead of `^(mng)?`?

Comment: @AdminBee No. `^(mng)?` is more elegant, though, I only did not use it because I didn't remember I could use `?` with a capture group. Thank you for reactivating a neural connection in my brain ;)

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Comment: In my experience on [so], this seems to be one of the most common errors of regex newbies. I've never gotten anyone to explain where they got the idea that `[]` is used for grouping instead of `()`, but it seems to be rampant.

Comment: @Barmar Manual pages use `[argument]` for optional arguments. Maybe some of them get it from there, while others most likely simply give it a shot.

Answer (score 9):

Quasimodo [already gave you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/617669/22222) the answer for why your regex was failing. I will suggest a different approach. Instead of regular expressions, use `case` and globs:

```bsh
case $(hostname -s) in
  kafka[0-9]*|mngkafka[0-9]*)
    /tmp/run.sh
esac
```

This is much easier to extend to more patterns and, personally, I find it easier to read.

Comment: Nice alternative with the Bonus of running in any POSIX shell.

Comment: Using `uname -n` instead of `hostname -s` would make it completely POSIX compliant. Note however that `[0-9]*` is not the same as regexp `[[:digit:]]+$` for which you'd need non standard glob extentions like `zsh -o extendedglob`'s `[0-9]##` or `ksh`/`zsh -o kshglob`/`bash -o extglob`'s `+([0-9])`. Except in the C/POSIX locale, `[0-9]` may (and often do) not match the same thing as `[[:digit:]]` or `[0123456789]`.